# Creating Custom UIButton But appearing not with correct height and gradient

Tags: ios

I am creating a subclass of UIButton and applying styles in code. For some reason my button does not pick up the custom gradient and also the height of the button is too small. How can I adjust the height of the uibutton to have more padding.

[image]

And here is the code:

```
@implementation DefaultButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    // Set the button Text Color
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    // Set default backgrond color
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    // Draw a custom gradient
    CAGradientLayer *btnGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    btnGradient.frame = self.bounds;
    btnGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0f / 255.0f green:102.0f / 255.0f blue:102.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f / 255.0f green:51.0f / 255.0f blue:51.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                          nil];
    [self.layer insertSublayer:btnGradient atIndex:0];

    // Round button corners
    CALayer *btnLayer = [self layer];
    [btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [btnLayer setCornerRadius:5.0f];

    // Apply a 1 pixel, black border around Buy Button
    [btnLayer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [btnLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For height you can do self.frame.size.height=30; (or whatever you want your height to be), place that in the init method.

As fas as gradient, I'm not sure